# How do I whitelist a JSP page with Tomcat's CSRFPrevention Filter?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have Tomcat's CSRFPrevention Filter working fine on my Tomcat 6.0.xx. I now would like to whitelist a single page (**that is, make it exempt from the filter being applied to it**). Under my `<filter-mapping>` in the `web.xml`, I have many URL patterns, one of them being:

`<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>`

This URL pattern encompasses about ~50 JSP pages. I would, however, like to whitelist one of these 50 pages. I would prefer not to have to add ALL of the 49 other pages to the `web.xml`. Is there anyway to whitelist just one page?

Answer (score 1):

Try `init-param` param `entryPoints` to skip the url, here it is `home`. Use csv for multiple urls:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
      <param-value>/home</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Attribute: ***entryPoints***
>
> Description: A comma separated list of URLs that ***will not be tested
>   for the presence of a valid nonce***. They are used to provide a way to
>   navigate back to a protected application after having navigated away
>   from it. Entry points will be limited to HTTP GET requests and ***should
>   not trigger any security sensitive actions***.

(Source: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CSRF_Prevention_Filter )

In your particular question case, you exclude only 1 item

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
        <param-value>/secure/foo.jsp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For the sake of generality, I have an example what exclude 2 JSP pages and 1 CSS file, set filter at top level web application directory.

```
<!-- CSRF Prevention Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
        <param-value>/web/pages/foo.jsp,/web/pages/bar.jsp,/web/en_US/css/style.css</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFPreventionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Read more: [This link](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/11477mk6sq/help-with-csrfpreventionfilter) will help the solution clearly.